# Load only some columns with Hibernate native SQL queries

Tags: sql, hibernate, native, loader

I have a table on the database and I want to load only some columns from the result set, because the main object mapped in Hibernate has a relation with itself and the object is very big. I defined a native sql query in the hbm file:

```
    <sql-query name="query">
  <return alias="r" class="RawData"/>    
     <![CDATA[
       SELECT DESCRIPTION as {r.description}
       FROM RAWD_RAWDATAS r       
       WHERE r.RAWDATA_ID=?
      ]]>
 </sql-query>
```

This query however fails with error: **could not read column value from result set: RAWDATA1_14_0_; Invalid column name SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: null**, because Hibernate tries to load all fields from the result set. I found also a bug in Hibernate JIRA (http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3035). Anyone knows how to accomplish this task with a workaround?

Comment: Similar question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186828/doubt-regarding-jpa-namedquery/4191511

Comment: Why don't you simply do a classical mapping of the columns you need, included RAWDATA_ID? Mapping them to an object and then work on that object to retrieve only DESCRIPTION field.

Comment: I can't do this because the relation is the following: RawData -> RawData, so RawData is itself linked.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a native SQL Query, you may need to use a Result Transformer:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer)

Edit:
The JPA feature for that is described here:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html

Comment: uh no, almost definitely not: that's applied to the results after they have been hydrated, just before they are returned to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select just a property, not an entity, specify `<return-scalar...>`, e.g.:

```
<sql-query name="AdvertDisplayRule.fetchActiveRuleSet">
    <return alias="ad" entity-name="com.wahanda.service.media.domain.Advert" />
    <return-scalar column="view_count" type="integer" />
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT {ad.*}, avd.view_count
    FROM adv.advert {ad}
         LEFT OUTER JOIN adv.advert_view_distribution avd ON avd.advert_id = {ad}.advert_id
    ]]>
</sql-query>
```

Comment: I want to select only some properties of an object, not the entire object, because the object can be very big and I don't want to load all the related collection of objects. I can't use your code because it returns a single property, not an object with a single property filled.

Comment: You could use a ResultTransformer to create your object and populate the single property... I think you've also put your finger on why non-lazy-loaded collections are usually a bad idea too.