# correct result type (not list)

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

How am I supposed to specify the result type of query like this:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.login, s.name FROM Student s, Users u").getResultList();
```

Comment: Similar question, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536655/jpa-native-query-join-returns-object-but-dereference-throws-class-cast-exception/4536802#4536802

Comment: Thanks for answer, but why I can't convert it to List of some POJO classes with 2 String fields?

Comment: Yes, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186828/doubt-regarding-jpa-namedquery/4191511#4191511 might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

createNativeQuery accepts a second parameter, which is the resulting class type.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)