# JPQL - exclude a property while querying

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have User object which has password too. How do i avoid reading password while i am listing users.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Similar one, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/4186828/366964

Comment: @JBNizet Because i don't want password to be listed when admin says list users.. :)

Comment: Errm, "listing" something in an output (HTML, etc) and having a field set in an object are two completely different things. Obviously JPQL supports specifying a result clause should you only want a part of an object